# Testing setting a private property: can we use the mock to set the value and reflect the property to check if value was set?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have both a "way of doing this" and "how is it done" question(s).

```
Class realClass {

     private $privateProperty;

     public function __construct($someArray, $someString) {
          // stuff
     }

     public function setProperty($someArray) {
          $this->privateProperty = $someArray;
     }
}


class testRealClass extends TestCase {

    // creating a mock because don't want to have tests depending on arguments passed to the constructor
    public function setUp(): void
    {
         $this->classToTest = $this->getMockBuilder(realClass::class)
             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
             ->setMethods(null)
             ->getMock();
    }

    // testing the set of the variable. In order to know if it was set, without using a getter,
    // we probably need to use reflection
    public function testSetPrivateProperty() {
         $this->classToTest->setProperty([1,2,3]);

         // This will not work as the property is private
         // echo $this->classToTest->privateProperty;

         // Reflecting the mock, makes sense? How does this work?
         $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($this->classToTest);
         $property = $reflect->getProperty('privateProperty');
         $property->setAccessible(true);
         var_dump($property->getValue($this->classToTest));
    }
}
```

When executing this I get a ReflectionException: Property privateProperty does not exist.

If I do a print_r of the reflections->getProperties I can see the property there.

I understand this would be easily achievable with just a getter in the realClass but take this as an exercise.

Doest this make sense at all or this will not work because it is just wrong?

Thank you everyone

(Wrote the code here so if I'm missing ";", "(", etc, do ignore it :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection API for testing is seldom a good idea. However, the real question is - why have a private property if nothing can access it? Obviously, the property is used in another method of the class. So, the clean solution here is remove all reflection code, then create a getter in the class itself, and replace all calls to `$this->property` to `$this->getProperty()`, then you can easily test this.

For a more generalized take on this question, private properties and methods are not meant to be tested, they are private because they conceal their data from everyone, including the tester classes. The more private fields and properties your class has, the less testable it gets, so when this becomes a hindrance, it is better to split the class into two, making one of the private methods public.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I do not agree with the first remark: I feel adding a getter just for sake of testing will, ultimately, make the "private" visibility component useless. Also you are coding for the tests, not for the sake of good code which is weird as well. Regarding the second part I'm not sure I understood it correctly but at first glance it seems you are also getting a solution to cover up the fact the property is private - that is not the issue and it must be private. The idea would be to make sure the value was set

Comment: Maybe the exercise is flawed - with a method that uses that private property, I think we could make sure the value was set, even if it is not a getter

Comment: @Consolas I agree that adding a getter for the sake of testing is a bad idea. However, if you think about it, you are not adding it for the sake of testing, you are adding it because you need to access the property somehow anyway, even from within the class, and accessing via getter is cleaner than without it.

Comment: @Consolas As for the second part, suppose you have `public function first()`, `private function second()` and `private function third()`. Now, your class has grown too big, it is hard to read and hard to test. What do you do? You move `third()` into another class and make it public. This is called "extract method" refactoring. Java has package privacy for such cases, in PHP there are no packages so making public is all we can do.

Comment: @Consolas If you are serious about making this exercise clean, well, keeping state on a class that has business logic is problematic, personally, I would create a data class with public getters and setters, and pass its instance as an argument to the class that handles business logic. It is a stricter implementation of Single Responsibility Principle, and this way, you never have to worry about situations like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your replies. Regarding the SRP, I don't think we would be violating it in this specific case. For instance: having a method that accepts an argument and adds to that argument this specific property we defined before, say, at the beginning of our software execution. Sure enough, that method would be enough to test the "set" of the property which would invalidate this exercise! :) thanks for the feedback guys